# Wordpress single.php another get_post function destory the first function

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I am trying to deal with two get_post functions, in single.php the first get_post function is the post from the wordpress, But after that I called get_post function to other post also to use both of them in the same page but after I call the first get_post ( the main post ) I get the only second data and cant reach the first data.
My code called to the second function ( The first is from wordpress post):

```
    $main_post = get_field('main_post');
    $main_p = get_post($main_post->ID);
```

Then I am trying to use the variable **`$post`** OR `the_title()` OR any other functions to get the first post and it always returning the info of the `$main_p` post

for example

```
get_the_title( get_post()->ID )
```

returns the `$main_p` post id and not the main post of the single.php

any soulutions ?

Comment: That is in part the intended functionality of the system. You are overwriting the post object that is retrieved from your database. Depending on what data you're trying to get from the 2nd post, there are a number of different ways to make what you want happen. What data are you trying to retrieve from the 2nd post (e.g. title, featured image, excerpt, content, etc...)?

Comment: @Ryan Yes i am trying to get title and content in the 2nd retrive

Comment: Can you post your template file code? That way, I can provide a real-world working option for you.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/fYFxRa7h a bit messy @Ryan

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but it seems to me that you are trying to post a different post format with normal post format?

I, myself use get_post_format() so it can be styled differently or have different options.

in single.php I use

```
     <!-- checking if there are any blogposts to be shown using have_posts check which is a wordpress function-->
      <?php if(have_posts()) : ?>
       <?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> <!-- the correct syntax for while loop in wordpress to show all the blogposts -->

        <?php get_template_part('content', get_post_format()); ?>

       <?php endwhile; ?>

      <?php else : //else stament if there aren't any posts (put inside if before endif)?>
       <p><?php __('No Posts Found'); ?></p>

      <?php endif; ?> <!-- stop checking for blog posts-->

    </div><!-- /.blog-main -->
```

Inside functions.php I activated the post-formats inside wp_theme_setup() function

```
add_theme_support('post-formats', array('aside', 'gallery'));
```

In this case i activated the gallery and aside posts

That way I have 2 different post types on one page

like this 
[image from my theme blog page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGb5M.png)

Here is also a video tutorial on post formats from Traversy media
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CRa7eiqyiCM&list=PLc5p9nvpdwBlrNU0hr1f0kXPRkh0aGo1Q&index=7

Comment: I don't think this will do the trick. What the poster is looking for is to pull content from a different post ID, not a different post format (i.e. getting the content from the last 2 blog posts on a single page).

Answer (score 0):

The key reason why your post values are being overwritten, the additional `get_post()` declarations are overriding the default query. Now, the code in your pastebin is a pretty massive dog's breakfast, so a direct solution is a rather large undertaking (e.g. the indentation is all over the place, the code snippets are less than ideal regarding their readability, etc...). However, I can point you in the right direction for the solution.

When I pull content from another page on my WordPress sites, I avoid using `get_post()` in favour of declaring a fresh `new WP_Query()` (that's just my preference), following it up with a `wp_reset_postdata()` declaration.

Here's an example of multiple queries on a single template in the WordPress codex:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Multiple_Loops

The key here is the `wp_reset_postdata()`. I'd recommend looking into it's purpose. It'll save you a lot of grief:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata